# unable to install visual studio 2008 sp1

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I got following error

```
failed with error: 12180
WinHttpDownloader::GetProxySetting) Auto detection of proxy failed, try to retrieve proxy information via IE.
WinHttpDownloader::GetProxySettingViaIE) Retrieving proxy information using WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser
WinHttpDownloader::GetProxySettingViaIE) Unable to retrieve Proxy information although WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser called succeeded
```

Please help me out i am getting issue from long time.

Answer (score 0):

try these links

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/0376db8f-4761-4ae5-9af2-98c53216318a#How_to_diagnoseVS2008_NETFramework_logs

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/2a3e870d-a655-4833-b0c8-2b7de5131dfd

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the installer you are using--a little tiny file about half a megabyte, right?--is trying to download all the pieces of the service pack, and it's searching for a web proxy via the autoproxy interface. So, you need to tell the system *not* to search for a web proxy, which you can do in the [Internet Explorer options here](http://www.library.kent.edu/page/14299#winie).

If that doesn't do the trick, then it's always possible to just [download the full version of VS2008 SP1 (in .ISO disc format)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=122095). (And, if you want the massive [MSDN Library for VS2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373&DisplayLang=en), it's available in full download form too.)